# My own version of quicksort only seems to work for small arrays

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, quicksort

I am trying to implement my own version on quicksort. I was very happy when I saw that it sorted for small arrays, but as soon as I tried on larger array inputs such as 1k, 50k, 100k, 1000k. I saw that the running time was higher than expected also when I tried with array input 1000k it caused stackoverflow.

I would love to get feedback on my code, what I should change in the code to make the algorithm work and comment on why it is currently not working with my code.

I have added `run_partition = false`, once I find out that the left pointer and right pointer points at same index. It made it possible to sort for an input array of 100k.

```
// O(nlogn) worst case running time
// O(n) space complexity
import java.util.*;
public class Quicksort {


    public int partition_array(int [] array, int start, int end) {
         // The pivot pointer starts at the first element initially, array index = 0
         // The left pointer points to first element initially

        int left_pointer = start;

        int right_pointer = end;
        int pivot_pointer =  left_pointer;
        boolean run_partition = true; 
        // keep running partition until we return a pivot index, once we return a partition index we can do quicksort on the values left to partition and values to right of partition
     while(run_partition) {


            if( pivot_pointer == left_pointer) {
                // If pivot points towards the left pointer then we have to make sure that all values to the right of pivot, make sure ew can sort duplicate keys too
                while(array[pivot_pointer] <= (array[right_pointer]) && right_pointer != pivot_pointer  ) {
                    right_pointer--;
                 }
                if(left_pointer == right_pointer) {
                // System.out.println(left_pointer + ": is same as  " + right_pointer);
                    run_partition=false;
                   return pivot_pointer;
                }
                // if pivot points towards left pointer and we find out that there exists a right value that is smaller, we have to swap them.
                else if(array[pivot_pointer] > (array[right_pointer]) )  {
                    // System.out.println("Right: " + array[right_pointer] + " is less than pivot_left:  " + array[pivot_pointer]);
                    swap(array, pivot_pointer, right_pointer);
                    pivot_pointer = right_pointer;

                }
                else if( right_pointer < left_pointer){
                break;
                }
                else {
                    right_pointer--;
                }
            }

            if(pivot_pointer == right_pointer) {
                // if pivot_pointer points towards right pointer then we have to make sure that all values to the left is smaller
                while(array[pivot_pointer] > ( array[left_pointer])  && left_pointer != pivot_pointer) {
                    // increment left_pointer until this while condition is no longer true
                    left_pointer++;
                }

                if(pivot_pointer == left_pointer) {
                    run_partition=false;
                    // System.out.println(left_pointer + "is same as " + right_pointer);
                    return pivot_pointer;
                }

                else if(array[pivot_pointer] < (array[left_pointer]))  {
                    // System.out.println("Left: " + array[left_pointer] + " er storre enn pivot:  " + array[pivot_pointer]);
                    swap(array, pivot_pointer, left_pointer);
                    pivot_pointer= left_pointer;
                }
                else if( left_pointer < 0){
                    break;
                    }
                else {
                    left_pointer++;
                }
            }             
        }
            return -1;

    }



    public void quicksort(int [] array, int start, int end) {

        // The pivot pointer starts at the first element initially, array index = 0
        // The left pointer points to first element initially
        // The right pointer points to last element initially
        // All elements to the right of pivot must be greater than pivot
        // All elements to the left of pivot must be smalelr than pivot
        // The pivot pointer starts at the first element initially, array index = 0
         // The left pointer points to first element initially
         if(end<=start || start>=end){
             return;
         }
         if(start <= end) {
            int partition_index = partition_array(array,start,end);
            quicksort(array,start,partition_index-1);
            quicksort(array,partition_index+1,end);

        }
        // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }

    public void swap(int[] array, int index_left, int index_right) {
        int temp = array[index_left];
        array[index_left] = array[index_right];
        array[index_right] = temp;
    }        
}
```

I expect the code to work for larger array input.

Comment: `end<=start` and `start>=end` are 2 ways of saying exactly the same thing, and if neither is true, `start<=end` must be (in fact, `start<end`).

Comment: Re: "I expect [...] that the running time should be running in O(nlogn) worst case running time": I don't understand why you would expect this from an implementation of [Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort), which has a worst-case time complexity of O(n²). Can you clarify where this expectation came from?

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm implementation uses recursion, given a large input your call stack grows, which is mostly likely what caused the program to stack overflow. You have to implement an iterative version to handle large arrays.

Comment: Scala @tailrec (tail recursion) can help you keep your implementation recursive and scalable. But well you'd have implement it in Scala.

Comment: Scala's tail call optimization wouldn't help here, since (as the name suggests) it can only optimize *tail* calls.